# How to PARSE HTML Files and SUBMIT information programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, parser-generator

ASP.NET 4 & C# and

I would like to know which CODE, Classes could be useful for creating a WEB APPLICATION that could:

```
01 - Connect to an HTML file on the web.
02 - Parse its content (text content).
03 - Find out specific content in a page (for example looking for specific keywords).
```

Also how to implement:

```
04 - How to submit information programmatically in HTML page (feeling forms).
```

I am interested in understanding Classes and general practice and CODE for accomplish this task.

If you have any idea please let me know. Thanks guys once again for your support! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want all of the things that you mention to execute 'server-side', but assuming that this is the case:

> 01 - Connect to an HTML file on the
>   web.

Check out the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) class, and the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class for more advanced scenarios.

> 02 - Parse its content (text content).
>   03 - Find out specific content in a
>   page (for example looking for specific
>   keywords).

You might want to look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or if Bobince doesn't notice, [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx).

> 04 - How to submit information
>   programmatically in HTML page (feeling
>   forms).

Typically, this will require sending a [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request, which too can be accomplished with the `HttpWebRequest` class.

Comment: @GIbboK: Sorry for not providing context, it was just a joke. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

For parsing the web page, have a look at the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). 
For form passing, you either need to use tools like Firebug or the Internet Explorer developer tools or use a sniffer like  Wireshark to see what is sent via the network.
I would also consider in your case to consider to split it into seperate components so that you can easily test parts of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to invoke a request to a page on the web.

You can then parse the HTML response.

To programmatically submit a form, i think you'll need to do it client-side (JavaScript):

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```